# fingerprint reader not working in dell vostro 3550

Tags: dell, fingerprint-reader

My laptop shows validity sensor device but the driver is not installed.Is it possible to install fingerprint reader. I have vfs5011 validity sensor

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/367705/driver-for-vfs5011-fingerprint-reader-on-dell-vostro-3550

Comment: Please be aware that using a fingerprint reader to replace your password is inherently insecure.

Comment: I got the driver file but there I couldnt find the configure  file as mentioned for ./configure.What shall I do?

Comment: I suggest that you ask the driver's creator. But remember that experimental drivers are for TESTING & demo purposes, not for practical use.

Answer (score 1):

You asked "I got the driver file but there I couldn't find the configure file as mentioned for `./configure`. What shall I do?"

Run:

```
sh autoconfig.sh" before you run "./config
```

I ran into the same issue, and now my Vostro Fprint scanner works.

Comment: Just checking, are you sure that the code syntax is fine?

Answer (score 0):

In short: forget it. No support yet for your VFS5011 reader on the fprint project.

And yes, a strong password is still better than any fingerprint reader:

[Fingerprint Scanners Are Unbeatable : Discovery Channel](http://dsc.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/fingerprint-scanners-unbeatable.htm)