# How to use fingerprint reader and card reader on my laptop running on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, dell-vostro

I have Dell Vostro 3560,which was originally shipped with Ubuntu,but then i moved to windows 8 and then i moved to Ubuntu 13.10 but i am unable to use fingerprint reader of my laptop to login.
I searched on internet and installed fprint but when i run it it shows no device found.
And i am also unable to use card reader on my laptop.
So please help me.
Result of `lsusb` is

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:648b Microdia Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have one of the supported finger scanners. You can check if your device is supported by checking [this](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/Supported_devices/) list of supported devices. To check which one you have, type

```
lsusb
```

I have Dell Vostro 3450 with:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
```

By the way for Dell i found this link, you could try it:

[Driver for VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader on Dell Vostro 3550](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367705/driver-for-vfs5011-fingerprint-reader-on-dell-vostro-3550)

Comment: please tell me how to debug fingerprint gui