# How do find out device by id shown by lsusb?

Tags: hardware, fingerprint-reader

I would like to buy Linux-supported fingerprint reader for desktop computer.
Launchpad [page](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui) for fingerprint-gui shows only list of supported device ids.

How to find out which devices they correspond to?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids or https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you Google the usb.id. The list of supported devices is shown here: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fingerprint-gui When I search for the first listed usb.id, 045e:00bb , I find this site: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint/Supported_devices/

It lists Vendor ID of 045e and Device ID 00bb as a Microsoft Keyboard with Fingerprint Reader.

Not every supported device is listed there; for example, 138a:0011. A Google search finds this: [Driver for VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader on Dell Vostro 3550](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367705/driver-for-vfs5011-fingerprint-reader-on-dell-vostro-3550) and this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Vostro_3360#Fingerprint_Reader We conclude, then, that the usb.id in question is associated with Dell Vostro 3550 and 3360 and, presumably, other similar Dells.